# Error involving dll when running C++ executable on another computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to share a simple program I made in VS2010 using C++, but when running on another computer I get an error. Here is the error message:

> The program can't start because MSVCR100D.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have the dll in the same folder, as I thought this would fix it. I'm using the debug executable, and the other computer doesn't have VS2010 installed which is what I think is causing the problem.

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: A simple search on "MSVCR100D.dll is missing from your computer" here at SO turned up many previous questions; the answers clearly explain the problem (and the solution). Please make at least a basic effort to search here for existing questions before posting a new one. It keeps down noise and clutter, and reduces duplication of effort. It also gets you a solution more quickly. Thanks.

Comment: First you need to build Retail rather than Debug if you want to run your program on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

Target machine needs to have Redistributable Package for Visual C++ 10.0 installed. Download it from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

You may also consider reading this section of MSDN to learn more about deployment process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9(VS.100).aspx

---

EDIT:

It seems that I missed that small 'd' in the DLL name. While this solution would be helpful in case of MSVCR100.dll (release version), it won't help you with the debug version, which you linked you application against. That's because debug DLLs are not included in redist packages - they are only shipped with Visual Studio.

Required DLLs (release builds) are placed in (VSInstallDir)\VC\redist(Platform)\Microsoft.VC100.CRT

Their debug versions can be found in (VSInstallDir)\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist(Platform)\Microsoft.VC100.Debug.CRT.

However, I don't think that making any effort to run debug build is a good solution. Providing release build is probably what you should do.

Comment: I don't think you can re-distribute the debug version of the c-runtime.

Comment: Oh, I missed that 'd' at the end. Running version linked against debug versrion of the CRT is indeed impossible without VS installed.